# Delete Key in UILabel is not working when code is correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I am creating a calculator app and the calculator screen is a UILabel. I am having trouble with a delete key. Here is my Code:

.h

```
IBOutlet UILabel *display;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)Del 
{
    [display.text substringToIndex:display.text.length -1];
}
```

it has no errors and runs in the simulator perfectly but does not actually work. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of the `substringToIndex:` method and you do not update the label's text.

You want something like this:

```
- (IBAction)Del {
    NSString *oldText = display.text;
    if (oldText.length > 0) {
        NSString *newText = [oldText substringToIndex:oldText - 1];
        display.text = newText;
    }
}
```

This also guards against trying to delete from an empty label.

Comment: @OnkaPlonka Shorter doesn't mean better. See what happens when you tap the delete button when the label is empty. The other code will crash.

Answer (score 2):

`-substringToIndex:` creates a copy of a part of the string to which it is sent.

What you have here creates such a string, and does nothing with it.

I suspect you want to assign that string to something, say, the `display.text` property:

```
- (IBAction)Del {
    display.text = [display.text substringToIndex:display.text.length -1];
}
```